# Microsoft Office Addin 2007 and 2010 Custom help topics

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-addins

I am responsible for a Office Add-in and need to know if it is possible to add help to the Microsoft Help for the add-in.  i.e. when F1 is pressed open a page in the help containing information on the add-in.

The only information that I have been able to find on the web relates to Excel but this needs to be a generic solution that will work for all the office applications if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can add sth to the build-in help. This is I think some *.chm file, so you would have to extend it or replace. 
I would rather add to the ribbon some button with link to the page where is your manual located or show it in the Word/Excel in an ActionPane.